# "Uncaught ImagickException: Invalid filename" on some JPEG files

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

My Imagick library seems to be working in most instances but throws the followingerror message when I attempt to upload certain JPEG files:

`Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: Invalid filename provided in D:\xampp\htdocs\socialnetwork\dashboard.php:68 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\socialnetwork\dashboard.php(68): Imagick->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\socialnetwork\dashboard.php on line 68`

I can find no common factors that seem to affect this result. It can happen at any bit depth but there does seem to be a pattern with higher resolution files. Renaming the file makes no difference either. I'm at a complete loss!

As an indicator, here are some example file names:

```
// Working

'10899370_774171245990712_1020727574_n.jpg'
'28062008013.jpg'
'800px-Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg.png'

// Not working

'DSC00806.jpg'
'daf.jpg'
'10899370_774171245990712_1020727574_q.jpg'
```

My source PHP is as follows:

```
<?php if (isset($_FILES["image_upload"]["name"])) { 

    $imagick = new Imagick($_FILES["image_upload"]["tmp_name"]);
    $imagick->resizeImage('400', '0', IMagick::FILTER_POINT, '1');
    $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );
    $imagick->setImageFormat ("jpeg");
    file_put_contents ('photos/'.$hash.'.jpg', $imagick);
    header('Location:dashboard.php');

} ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Upload image</label><input type="file" name="image_upload" id="image_upload">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You could post one of the file names as well.

Comment: It doesn't really seem to make much difference hence why I left it out, but I'll add that in.

Comment: the way you're creating the hash, you're bound to get a collision quite soon. why don't you hash the image itself, or create a GUID?

Comment: The hash probably won't make the cut for that very reason but that certainly isn't the issue here. I am still getting the error message even when 'photos/' is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out Imagick was kicking out unhelpful error messages. The issue was the uploaded file sizes exceeded the maximum allowed size for uploaded files in php.ini.

I'm not sure why I wasn't getting an error message from the server but there we have it. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

"Problems with higher resolution files and renaming the files makes no difference" indicates to me it is a problem with the file. The invalid filename is probably misleading.
With imagemagick directly you can get a similar error with a filename when the image conversion process fails before it is saved.

I would try running one of the files directly in Imagemagick and see if you get a different error and or check your server logs to see if there is any more detail. You could also try reducing your command to a simple/minimum to see if one of your operations in particular is causing the problem. Also use hardcoded values with all files in the same folder.

```
$array=array();
echo "<pre>";
exec("convert DSC00806.jpg Output_test1.png 2>&1", $array); 
echo "<br>".print_r($array)."<br>";
echo "</pre>";
```

Replace convert with magic if using V7

Comment: I have managed to open the problem files in ImageMagick succesfully, and have simplified my command with no success... but I'm afraid I don't really understand the rest of your instructions...

Comment: That is good so you have ruled out a problem with the files. I am at a loss as to what the problem is then. The code posted should display any errors caught by Imagemagick. Checking your log files in the folder where the code is might highlight any problems/errors not displayed by Imagick.

Comment: Annoyingly, log file shows exactly the same error. Thanks for your help though!